# Flutter firestore returns length 0 while there is data in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in flutter:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
    await _firestore.collection("user1@gmail.com").get();

List Data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();

print("Length: ${Data.length}");
```

Here is my firestore database:

[image]

I get the following output:

> I/flutter (11484): Length: 0

The Documents for each user email is variable, so I need the length of the documents. Also I need to get to the details of each document like content and title. How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: May you share with us the output from `querySnapshot.docs.length`?

Comment: yes. querySnapshot.docs.length returns also 0

Comment: have you checked if you have added google-services.json into your project?

Comment: Yes, it is added.

Comment: Have you try "querySnapshot.size"?

Comment: yes it is same 0

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
int size = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionPath).get(GetOptions(source:Source.server))..size;
```

I will recommend finding a way to store the length of documents as a field in your Cloud Firestore database because calling the get function on a whole collection means filling up the mobile phone memory. (Say you have **500,000** users at least). This makes your app slow

You could have a field called count such that when you add a document, you can use the firebase transaction to update firebase.

For example:

```
// Create a reference to the document the transaction will use
DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(documentId);

return FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  // Get the document
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(documentReference);

  if (!snapshot.exists) {
    throw Exception("User does not exist!");
  }

  // Update the follower count based on the current count
  // Note: this could be done without a transaction
  // by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()

  // Perform an update on the document
  transaction.update(documentReference, {'followers': FieldValue.increment(1);});

  // Return the new count
  return newFollowerCount;
})
.then((value) => print("Follower count updated to $value"))
.catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user followers: $error"));
```

You can see more documentations here: [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage)